# Powering a Sim800L Module

Tags: arduino-nano, power

I am trying to use a DC [power supply](https://mcs.com.bd/product/dazheng-ps-305d-dc-power-supply-3-digit-0v-30v-0a-5a/). I am thinking whether I can use this power supply to provide power for [Sim800L](https://nettigo.eu/products/sim800l-gsm-grps-module) module. After some research, I gathered that the Sim800L module requires a max current of 2A during GPRS transmission at 3.8-4.2 V (4.0 recommended). With the power supply I can easily configure the voltage at 4.0V. My question is: for this setup, do I need a [DC-DC](https://www.addicore.com/lm2596-module-p/ad281.htm) Buck Converter as in this one for regulation/step-down (not sure which)?

Comment: Li-Po batteries blow up very easily and require specific hardware to charge (check drone power supply issues).  please  be VERY CAREFUL charging Li-Po batteries (if you are following https://lastminuteengineers.com/sim800l-gsm-module-arduino-tutorial/#supplying-power-for-sim800l-module).  Li-Po ba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lab power supply you linked is serious overkill for your needs. It shouldn't need a separate voltage regulator or buck converter, since I assume that it provdes a voltage and current regulated supply.

A regulated, fixed voltage 4V power supply that can provide 2A is what you want. That will probably cost < 1/10 of the amount of the lab supply you linked. The challenge is to find a 4V supply. (Most regulated power supplies are either 3.3V or 5V, since those are common voltages for solid state electronics.)

That said, the linear voltage regulators are usually adjustable with a decent voltage range using a resistor.

You could always build your own voltage regulator using a linear voltage regulator rated for 2A, plus a resistor and a couple of capacitors. You could either feed it from an unregulated 6V power supply or use a transformer, bridge rectifier, and capacitor to provide an unregulated DC input to a voltage regulator.

### Edit:

With a little googling I found a few 4V 2A power supplies online. This one, for example:

https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/US-AC110-220V-To-DC-4V_62155516966.html?spm=a2700.7724857.normalList.14.a5e64009aUU1ln&s=p

(That link is to a wholesale manufacturer that sells them in volume, but you may be able to find the same supply for single unit sale. A 2A switching 4V supply would meet your needs as well)